# Why eclipse is creating/running multiple java process in ubuntu?

Tags: java, spring-boot, eclipse, ubuntu, ide

Why eclipse is creating multiple java process in ubuntu? It eats lots of `RAM`, How to disable/optimize?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure they are all from Eclipse? Please show the details. Which Eclipse IDE package of which version do you have and do you have additional plugins installed? Is this a fresh installation? How is the question related to the tag `spring-boot`?

Comment: It is `Version: 2022-09 (4.25.0)`. First 2 process are eclipse related. 3rd is spring boot app. It is fresh installation with an additional plugin `STS`

Comment: Which IDE package? Which STS version? How is the question related to the tag `spring-boot`? With which Java do you run Eclipse? When you do what? Why two of three Java processes (how can this be seen from what you show)? Please improve your question.